# why does JTable createDefaultEditors use lambda expressions?

Tags: java, swing, lambda

Can someone explain what is going on here, and why LazyValue an lambda expressions are used?

```
protected void createDefaultEditors() {
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass = new UIDefaults(3, 0.75f);

        // Objects
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass.put(Object.class, (UIDefaults.LazyValue) t -> new GenericEditor());

        // Numbers
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass.put(Number.class, (UIDefaults.LazyValue) t -> new NumberEditor());

        // Booleans
        defaultEditorsByColumnClass.put(Boolean.class, (UIDefaults.LazyValue) t -> new BooleanEditor());
    }
```

Comment: Presumably so the editors are not created if not needed. The [JavaDoc for `LazyValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.LazyValue.html) says as much.